# Calling function to run when idle in matlab

Tags: matlab, interrupt, idle-processing

Is it possible in matlab to call a function when the program I'm running is idle? I don't want this to be a parallel process. Also, I would prefer a solution where I could pause and resume the function when the main program has to run again. Kind of like an interrupt in embedded systems, in my case the main program is the interrupt.

how would I do this?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but you can pause execution using `pause on; pause`... Don't know if this helps...

Answer (score 0):

you could use a timer object to start / stop the second function. see the [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-38272.html). See also [this mathworks blog entry.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/05/advanced-matlab-timer-objects/)